# Дружественный метод шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

### header.h

```
template <typename T>
class example {
public:
    example() { p = nullptr; };
    example(T x, T y, T z) {
        p = new Point<T>(x, y, z);
    };
    ~example() { if (p != nullptr) delete p; }

    template <typename T>
    class Point {
    public:
        Point(T x, T y, T z) {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
            this->z = z;
        }

        T x, y, z;
    };

    void get_point();
    friend void set_point(example<T> & ex, T x, T y, T z);
    Point<T> * p;
};

template<typename T>
void example<T>::get_point() {
    cout << p->x << endl;
    cout << p->y << endl;
    cout << p->z << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void set_point(example<T> & ex, T x, T y, T z) {
    ex.p->x = x;
    ex.p->y = y;
    ex.p->z = z;
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;   


int main() {
    example<int> ex(12,20,15);
    ex.get_point();
    set_point(ex,5,25,35);
    ex.get_point();

    return 0;
}
```

Компилируется без ошибок, но когда запускаю без отладки выдает:

> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl
>   set_point(class example &,int,int,int)"
>   (?set_point@@YAXAEAV?$example@H@@HHH@Z) в функции main

и не запускает. Почему?

Comment: Почему `set_point` не определен как метод класса `example`? Это не относится к ошибке, просто непонятна логика.

Comment: Это я так friend метод добавил к методам шаблонного класса. Когда тоже самое без шаблонов делаю, ошибок нет.

Comment: Метод самого класса не может быть `friend`, если вы ставите это ключевое слово то это уже не метод. Поэтому вам и приходится добавлять параметр ссылку на `example`

Comment: Тема уже много раз всплывала. Смотрите дубликаты: там есть все варианты правильного объявления. У вас есть **три** разных варианта решения этой проблемы, каждый со своими особенностями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно  дружествунную функцию обьявить в классе такой же, какой вы ее определяете, т.е. она должна быть обьявлена шаблонной, но не с тем аргументом шаблона какой у класса, поскольку это не член класса, а всего лишь функция, пользующийся его закрытыми и защищенными членами:

```
template < class Y >
friend void set_point(example<Y> & ex, Y x, Y y, Y z);
```

То же самое касается и  вложенному классу:

```
template <typename U> // а не typename T
class Point {
public:
    Point(U x, U y, U z) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
    }

    U x, y, z;
};
```

Плюс, после определения функции(тела функции) точка с запятой есть синтаксическая ошибка, так что уберите их после определения конструкторов.
Других ошибок не вижу...

Comment: Спасибо, Вы - гений!

Comment: Нет, просто  когда я чем то занимаюсь, пытаюсь  это делать хорошо, чего и желаю вам...